# Implementing Leadbolt in Android app

Tags: android, ads, leadbolt

I am making my first Android app and I am trying to implement Leadbolt unlocker, I have done everything like Leadbolt documentation, but when I launch app it is always crashing. When I remove implement AdListener from `public class FullActivity extends Activity implements AdListener` then everything is working. App is crashing when `Intent full = new Intent(GridActivity.this, FullActivity.class);` and it is not even go to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` breakpoint. 
This is FullActivity.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.Leadbolt.AdController;
import com.Leadbolt.AdListener;

public class FullActivity extends Activity implements AdListener{
private AdController myController;
private String MY_LB_SECTION_ID="1111111";

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.p1, 
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.p3, 
        R.drawable.p4,
        R.drawable.p5, 
        R.drawable.p6,
        R.drawable.p7,
        R.drawable.p8,
        R.drawable.p9, 
        R.drawable.p10,
        R.drawable.p11, 
        R.drawable.p12,
        R.drawable.p13, 
        R.drawable.p14,
        R.drawable.p15,
        R.drawable.p16,
        R.drawable.p17, 
        R.drawable.p18,
        R.drawable.p19, 
        R.drawable.p20,
        R.drawable.p21, 
        R.drawable.p22,
        R.drawable.p23, 
        R.drawable.p24,
        R.drawable.p25, 
        R.drawable.p26,
        R.drawable.p27, 
        R.drawable.p28,
        R.drawable.p29,
        R.drawable.p30,
        R.drawable.p31, 
        R.drawable.p32,
        R.drawable.p33, 
        R.drawable.p34,
        R.drawable.p35, 
        R.drawable.p36,
        R.drawable.p37,
        R.drawable.p38,
        R.drawable.p39, 
        R.drawable.p40,
        R.drawable.p41, 
        R.drawable.p42,
        R.drawable.p43, 
        R.drawable.p44,
        R.drawable.p45,
        R.drawable.p46, 
        R.drawable.p47,
        R.drawable.p48, 
        R.drawable.p49,
        R.drawable.p50
};

Integer imageId;
TouchImageView touch;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Activity act = FullActivity.this; 
    final AdListener listener = FullActivity.this; 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {
        imageId = extras.getInt("image");
        touch = new TouchImageView(this);
        Bitmap snoop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mThumbIds[imageId]);
        touch.setImageBitmap(snoop);
        touch.setMaxZoom(4f); //change the max level of zoom, default is 3f
        setContentView(touch);
    }

    final String PREFS_NAME = "AppPrefs";

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int ad = settings.getInt("ad", 0);

    if((imageId > 25)&&(ad < 1)){

        touch.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run(){ 
                myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID, 
                        listener); 
                myController.loadAd(); 
            } 
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.set_back:
            setBack();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void setBack() {
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(mThumbIds[imageId]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(FullActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Wallapers set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void onDestroy(){ 
    myController.destroyAd(); 
    super.onDestroy(); 
}

public void onAdClicked() {}

public void onAdClosed() {}

public void onAdCompleted() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("ad", 1);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}

public void onAdFailed() {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            if(myController != null){ 
                myController.destroyAd(); 
            } 
        } 
    });
}

public void onAdLoaded() {}

public void onAdProgress() {}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

We have made some adjustments to the code which should resolve this for you.

```
package com.mkstudio.hdwallpapers;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.Leadbolt.AdController;
import com.Leadbolt.AdListener;

public class FullActivity extends Activity{
private AdController myController;
private String MY_LB_SECTION_ID="729926945";

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.p1, 
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.p3, 
        R.drawable.p4,
        R.drawable.p5, 
        R.drawable.p6,
        R.drawable.p7,
        R.drawable.p8,
        R.drawable.p9, 
        R.drawable.p10,
        R.drawable.p11, 
        R.drawable.p12,
        R.drawable.p13, 
        R.drawable.p14,
        R.drawable.p15,
        R.drawable.p16,
        R.drawable.p17, 
        R.drawable.p18,
        R.drawable.p19, 
        R.drawable.p20,
        R.drawable.p21, 
        R.drawable.p22,
        R.drawable.p23, 
        R.drawable.p24,
        R.drawable.p25, 
        R.drawable.p26,
        R.drawable.p27, 
        R.drawable.p28,
        R.drawable.p29,
        R.drawable.p30,
        R.drawable.p31, 
        R.drawable.p32,
        R.drawable.p33, 
        R.drawable.p34,
        R.drawable.p35, 
        R.drawable.p36,
        R.drawable.p37,
        R.drawable.p38,
        R.drawable.p39, 
        R.drawable.p40,
        R.drawable.p41, 
        R.drawable.p42,
        R.drawable.p43, 
        R.drawable.p44,
        R.drawable.p45,
        R.drawable.p46, 
        R.drawable.p47,
        R.drawable.p48, 
        R.drawable.p49,
        R.drawable.p50
};

Integer imageId;
TouchImageView touch;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.full);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {
        imageId = extras.getInt("image");
        touch = new TouchImageView(this);
        Bitmap snoop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mThumbIds[imageId]);
        touch.setImageBitmap(snoop);
        touch.setMaxZoom(4f); //change the max level of zoom, default is 3f
        setContentView(touch);
    }

    final String PREFS_NAME = "SexyRec";

    final Activity act = this; 

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int ad = settings.getInt("ad", 0);

    if((imageId > 25)&&(ad < 1)){

        touch.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run(){ 
                myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID, new AdListener() {                   
                    public void onAdProgress() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }                       
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }                       
                    public void onAdFailed() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }                       
                    public void onAdCompleted() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SexyRec", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putInt("ad", 1);

                        // Commit the edits!
                        editor.commit();

                    }                       
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }                       
                    public void onAdClicked() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }); 
                myController.loadAd(); 
            } 
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.set_back:
            setBack();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void setBack() {
    //chuckNorris.setResourceAsWallpaper(mThumbIds[imageId]);
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(mThumbIds[imageId]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(FullActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Wallapers set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void onDestroy(){ 
    myController.destroyAd(); 
    super.onDestroy(); 
}
```

}

Comment: is it necessary to activate admob account or its independent from admob account?

Comment: Good question! If you are looking to use Leadbolt with AdMob mediation, then check out our integration guides here (you will need to integrate SDKs from both networks).

Android: https://help.leadbolt.com/using-admob-android/
iOS: https://help.leadbolt.com/using-admob-ios/

Otherwise, you can always integrate Leadbolt independently from other networks. Check out our help guides here (according to your platform and framework). https://help.leadbolt.com/app-developers/